# White rectangle identification

Tags: uitableview, ios4, view

In an iPhone app I get the following phenomenon, when handling (rotating) a UITableView.
(The problem may have nothing to do with UITableView itself, but….)

When I rotate: things appear OK for the vertical view, but for the horizontal view I get a white rectangle in the upper left corner. How this can be? I expect a View not being where it ought to be or not being set up as it ought to. But if this is the case how can I identify this view? I did not find anything suspicious in my code. And apart from this rectangle coming from nowhere, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was due to a difference in the resources. Under Interface Builder I found that the resources I used for the vertical and horizontal views were not set up the same way. After changing that, the problem disappeared.